# Automatically finding starting values for a sigmoid curve

Tags: statistics, curve-fitting, data-fitting, nonlinear-optimization, sigmoid

I have ~10.000 of vectors and I want to fit a sigmoid curve to each of them; in each case, I need to define starting parameters for fitting, so I want to find these parameters automatically. On stackexchange, there are discussed strategies of automatically finding starting values for non-linear models ([one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160552/why-is-nls-giving-me-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-parameter-estimates), [two](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62995/how-to-choose-initial-values-for-nonlinear-least-squares-fit)), but these discussions consider some specific cases such as fitting a gaussian. Are there general stratagies which can be applied to sigmoid curve too?

Answer (score 0):

If there were general methods, they would be generally implemented. You need special case methods.

If for example your sigmoid function is like:

```
S(x) = L / (1 + exp( -k*(x-x0))
```

so that you want to find L, k and x0, you could proceed like this:

I'll call your data x[] and y[]

Find the maximum of the y[] and take something a bit greater than that as the estimate of L

Transform the y[] to be

```
z[i] = log( L/y[i] - 1)
```

(note that if L is the maximum of the y[] then the z for those y that are the maximum will be undefined, which is why you should take L to be greater than the maximum; alternatively you could just miss out the z's where the y's are the maximum)

so that the relationship you seek is

```
z[i] ~ -k*(x[i]-x0)
```

and then estimate k and x0 using linear least squares on x[], z[]